# Allow nullable strings and List<string> as datatype in Entity Framework Model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model class defined as:

```
public class EventReg
{
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Event Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Event Time")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }

        public List<string> HashTags { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Registered by")]
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }

        public float Latitude { get; set; }
        public float Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Questions:

1. Now I don't really know that whether there will be a *category* and *Hash Tags* for every event. So, I want to register these fields as *Nullable* but when I defined these fields as  *System.Nullable* for  *category* or *System.Nullable >* for *HashTags*, there was an error saying `"The type string/List<string> must be non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type or method'System.Nullable<T>'"`. How to counter this error?
2. I wanted to be able to update the database schema later so used *package manager console(add-migration intial command)* to create an *datetime_initial.cs* file which will be executed everytime I call *update-database*. But due to some reason the field HashTags was not listed in the datetime_initial.cs file created. Why?

Comment: The whole story here is that the string datatype already _IS_ nullable by design. So you don't need to make anything here (and also you're not allowed to).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class EventReg
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // !!!
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; } // added "?"

    [Display(Name = "Event Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EventTime { get; set; } // added "?"

    public virtual ICollection<string> HashTags { get; set; } // changing List to ICollection virtual
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Registered by")]
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }

    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Also, feel free to get rid of EventDate and EventTime, because DateTime is holding date and time:

```
public DateTime? EventDateStamp { get; set; }
```

You can define your own read-only properties if you need a time or data. But it's not recommended to do this in model, because it's considered as a good practice if you keep your model consistent, and when your model is not dependent on how are you going to show it to the user. You can use view models for this purpose and use [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) tool for that.

One more advice is to get rid of DateTime and use DateTimeOffset:

```
public DateTimeOffset? EventDateStampUtc { get; set; }
```

with universal date and time:

```
model.EventDateStampUtc = DateTimeOffset.Utc;
```

The main benefit of using UTC time is that you don't need to think about date and time if you have multiple servers, located in other countries, with different times and timezones. Also, you and your customers are not dependent on the server's timezone.

And since this question is about ASP.NET MVC, I can suggest you may want to display this date and time later in your view. I recommend to use wonderful [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library on the client side for this purpose.

> ...which will be executed everytime I call update-database...

Use `Seed` method in your `Migrations\Configuration.cs` for this purposes:

```
protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
{
    context.MyEntities.AddOrUpdate(
        e => e.Key,
        new MyEntity { aa = 1, bb = 2, key = "unique-001" },
        new MyEntity { aa = 11, bb = 22, key = "unique-002" }       
    );
}
```

Some useful options in Configuration constructor:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; // take care!
}
```

Comment: @RomanPushkin...adding a ? will make other fields nullable i.e. they can accept null as a value. How is it making category and HashTags nullable? Also, any ideas about 2nd question?

Comment: I've just updated an answer for the second question.

Comment: Actually, string is a kind of special object. You can use String.IsNullOrEmpty to check if your strings are empty. Btw, why do you want your strings to be nullable?

Comment: @Roman...so that we can insert NULL as the content in a database for the field if we don't know its value or the field is not applicable(N/A)

Comment: @Roman...why should HashTags field be virtual and also what is the benefit of ICollection over List

Comment: With virtual they're lazy loaded. ICollection is a contract (EF needs Add property) and not implementation. Theoretically, List implementation can be changed, and won't implement ICollection any longer (now it implements ICollection, IEnumerable, and IList). A good object oriented practice is to program towards the interface, and not concrete implementation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43663/discussion-between-avinash-and-roman-pushkin)